# Problems Deleting Sub-Arrays that Satisfy Some Criterion

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate an array of arrays, and then delete all sub-arrays that satisfy some condition. However, my code does not seem to be doing this, and I am not sure why.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = np.arange(.01,1,.01)
h1 = np.arange(.01,1,.01)
h2 = np.arange(.01,1,.01)
e_given_d = np.arange(.01,1,.01)
e_h1_h2 = np.array(np.meshgrid(e,h1,h2)).T.reshape(-1,3)
e_h1_ed = np.array(np.meshgrid(e,h1,e_given_d)).T.reshape(-1,3)
e_h2_ed = np.array(np.meshgrid(e,h2,e_given_d)).T.reshape(-1,3)
h1_h2_ed = np.array(np.meshgrid(h1,h2,e_given_d)).T.reshape(-1,3)
e = np.concatenate((e_h1_h2[:,0],e_h2_ed[:,0],e_h1_ed[:,0]),axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
h1 = np.concatenate((e_h1_h2[:,1],e_h1_ed[:,1],h1_h2_ed[:,0]),axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
h2 = np.concatenate((e_h1_h2[:,2],e_h2_ed[:,1],h1_h2_ed[:,1]),axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
e_given_d = np.concatenate((e_h1_ed[:,2],e_h2_ed[:,2],h1_h2_ed[:,2]),axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
all_combos = np.hstack((e,h1,h2,e_given_d))


e = all_combos[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
h1 = all_combos[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
h2 = all_combos[:,2].reshape(-1,1)
e_given_d = all_combos[:,3].reshape(-1,1)
h2_given_e_x_e_given_d = ((.97*h2/e)*e_given_d).reshape(-1,1)


h2_given_not_e = (.03*h2/(1-e)).reshape(-1,1)


not_e_given_d = (1-e_given_d).reshape(-1,1)


max2 = np.maximum(h2_given_not_e,not_e_given_d)


ex_power_2 = (h2_given_e_x_e_given_d-max2)/(h2_given_e_x_e_given_d+max2)


h1_given_e_x_e_given_d = ((1*h1/e)*e_given_d).reshape(-1,1)


h1_given_not_e = (0*h1/(1-e)).reshape(-1,1)


max1 = np.maximum(h1_given_not_e,not_e_given_d)


ex_power_1 = (h1_given_e_x_e_given_d-max1)/(h1_given_e_x_e_given_d+max1)


initial_important_combos = np.hstack((e,h1,h2,e_given_d,ex_power_1,ex_power_2))



sufficient_combos = np.delete(initial_important_combos, np.where(e+.00001>.97),0)
sufficient_combos1 = np.delete(sufficient_combos, np.where(h1+.00001>(.97/.03)*(1-e_given_d)*(1-e)),0)


print(sufficient_combos1)
```

When I run the program, sufficient_combos1 includes the sub-array

[ 0.73        0.73        0.98        0.99        0.98        0.84422845]

However, .73>(.97/.03)*(1-.99)*(1-.73)=.0873.  So, as I understand the code above, this array should have been removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to run the code but it gives an error: `e = np.concatenate((e_h1_h2[:,0], e_h2_ed[:,0], e_h1_ed[:,0]), axis=1)` "AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1"

Comment: Hmmm this is strange, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this, the issue is that I was using the names of vectors rather than columns of matrices in the scope of np.where, e.g. 'e' needed to be replaced by initial_important_combos[:,0].